# Tkinter/Python - Simple Login Application NoneType Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to develop a simple login desktop app with tkinter lib. My code is working but when I'm trying to login with correct username and password it's giving the NoneType error. I am writing my codes on Pycharm. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
rootname = "Casca"
rootpasswd = "12345"
def loginfunc():
    passwd=plogin.get()
    name=ulogin.get()
    if name==rootname and passwd==rootpasswd:
        print("Successfull Login")
    else:
        print("Unauthorized User")
username=Label(text="Username:",font="Consolas,20").grid(row=0,column=0)
ulogin=Entry(font="Consolas,20",width=8).grid(row=0,column=1)
passwd=Label(text="Password:",font="Consolas,20").grid(row=1,column=0)
plogin=Entry(font="Consolas,20",width=8,show="*").grid(row=1,column=1)
sremember=Checkbutton(text="I forgot my password",font="Consolas,20").grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
login=Button(text="Login",font="Consolas,20",command=loginfunc).grid(row=3,column=0)
window=mainloop()
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BLABLABLA", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "BLABLABLA", line 9, in loginfunc
    passwd=plogin.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1):

`Entry()` returns the instance of the tkinter entry widget

`Entry().grid()` returns NoneType.

Change your code as shown below

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
rootname = "Casca"
rootpasswd = "12345"
def loginfunc():
    passwd=plogin.get()
    name=ulogin.get()
    if name==rootname and passwd==rootpasswd:
        print("Successfull Login")
    else:
        print("Unauthorized User")
username=Label(text="Username:",font="Consolas,20").grid(row=0,column=0)

ulogin=Entry(font="Consolas,20",width=8)
ulogin.grid(row=0,column=1)
passwd=Label(text="Password:",font="Consolas,20").grid(row=1,column=0)
plogin=Entry(font="Consolas,20",width=8,show="*")
plogin.grid(row=1,column=1)
sremember=Checkbutton(text="I forgot my password",font="Consolas,20").grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
login=Button(text="Login",font="Consolas,20",command=loginfunc).grid(row=3,column=0)
window=mainloop()
```

You will have to do the same thing with the checkbox to get it's value.
You should also consider IntVar and StringVar variables to store the contents of these widgets.

Comment: It worked scotty! now I understood the logic that you are trying to tell me :)

Comment: @Casca Great. If we were able to help, accept the answer that helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `plogin = Entry(...).grid(...)` you replace `plogin` with the result of `.grid()`, which is `None`. To fix this, you could do:

```
plogin = Entry(...)
plogin.grid(...)
```

and similar for all the other widgets.

Comment: you are awesome pycoder! I applied your solution and it worked! Love you all guys!